# Access to contextvars in asyncio add_done_callback callback

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asynccallback, python-contextvars

In Python async function I'am creating ContextVar, task and attaching callback to it:

```
bbb = contextvars.ContextVar('aaa')
bbb.set(3)
task = self.loop.create_task(self.someFunc())
task.add_done_callback(self.commonCallback)
bbb.set(4)
```

In callback I first start debugger:

```
def commonCallback(self, result):
 pdb.set_trace()
 try:
  r = result.result()
  print(r)
 except:
  self.log.exception('commonCallback')
```

And in debugger:

```
-> try:
(Pdb) bbb.get()
*** NameError: name 'bbb' is not defined
(Pdb) ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
(Pdb) print(list(ctx.items()))
[(<ContextVar name='aaa' at 0xa8245df0>, 3)]
(Pdb)
```

ContextVar is there, but I can't access it. So, I am missing something, but can't find what?

Comment: Why do you expect the `bbb` local variable defined in one function to be accessible in the `commonCallback` function defined elsewhere in the code? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) states that "Context Variables should be created at the top module level".

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, that was it. I knew it was trivial, and it was, as usual. I just couldn't see it. Sadly, I do not have enough reputation to upvote comment.

Comment: No problem, I've now posted a similar suggestion as an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bbb` local variable is defined in one place, so it won't be automatically accessible in another, such as the `commonCallback` function defined elsewhere in the code. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) states that "Context Variables should be created at the top module level", so you should try that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from context without importing top level module.
contextvars.Context has __iter__ method. And you can use a for loop to get the value:

```py
def get_ctx_var_value(ctx, var_name, default_value=None):
    for var in ctx:
        if var.name == var_name:
            return ctx[var]
    return default_value

ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
var_value = get_ctx_var_value(ctx, 'aaa')
```